# Selenium Python XPath Find Element that has a child/grandchild

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm new to Python Selenium and trying to select the ui-button tag in the following DOM structure:

```
...
<div>
    <ui-button>
        <button type='submit'>TEST</button>
    </ui-button>
</div>
```

There's a lot of HTML in this document which I havent included, so I understand that an efficient XPath statement can accomplish this but don't know how to do it.

There's multiple ui-button tags in the page, but only one with a child button type='submit', and the goal is to click on the ui-button tag with selenium. There's no other easy way to identify these tags. So what I was doing was selecting the submit button with a css selector then using XPath to go up 1 parent, but I need to be able to select the ui-button with a single statement.

This is my best attempt:

```
"./ui-button/input[@type='submit']"
```

I'm trying to select the ui-button with a child input button that is of type 'submit'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To select the parent `ui-button` node according to it's child with `type='submit'` you can use any of the following XPaths:

```
//ui-button[./button[@type='submit']]
```

or

```
//button[@type='submit']/..
```

or

```
//button[@type='submit']/../..//ui-button
```

But all this seems strange to me sense normally you have to click the `button` element, not element with strange tag name like `ui-button`.
However if `<button type='submit'>TEST</button>` is not the immediate child of the `ui-button` element you can use only one option from the 3 mentioned above with a slight change:

```
//ui-button[.//button[@type='submit']]
```

this means: an element with `ui-button` tag name somewhere on the page having somewhere inside it an element matching `//button[@type='submit']` locator

Comment: Thanks that's awesome appreciate it. Also so I know in the future, how would i select the ui-button tag if i knew it had a child <button type='submit'> but didnt know how much farther down in the DOM the button is (i.e. not an immediate child)

Comment: @GeoffL have I answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the full XPath you can go to chrome and simply right-click -> Inspect to go to the chrome developer tools. Then you can right-click on the element in the HTML, go to copy, and click Copy Full XPath. Then you can use find_element_by_xpath(XPath goes here) to find the element.